# Can mssql-cli run a sql script file?

Tags: sql-server

I have a sql script called database_create.sql.
On Windows, I can run this from sqlcmd as follows:

```
sqlcmd -U sa -P Password -S 192.168.nnn.mmm -i database_create.sql -o output.txt
```

I want to run the same script on Linux (Centos7).
I have mssql-cli version 0.15.0 but cannot find out how to get it to run my sql script.

A thread on github (https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli/issues/139) suggests it's not possible yet.

I can't believe Microsoft haven't duplicated the sqlcmd functionality in mssql-cli. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Upvote the issue on github, if you have not already done so.

Comment: ```-i , --input_file     Specifies the file that contains a batch of SQL statements for processing.```, per [Usage Guide](https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli/blob/master/doc/usage_guide.md#options)

Answer (score 1):

I installed mssql-tools which contains bcp and sqlcmd.